# Is there a way to stop accessibility services to interact with my android application?

Tags: android, accessibility

I am working on an application, where I want to restrict accessibility service to interact with my android application.

[[link]](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity14/sec14-paper-lau.pdf) This paper designs a transparent overlay on top of the screen using an accessibility service to intercept all the input/output from an application. I am wondering is there a way to bypass this interception?

Comment: [Accessibility services are needed for those with different abilities](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility). My guess is that the 2014 paper was referring to `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` abuse which had its behavior/permission behavior modified in [Android 8](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#all-aw) and in [Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions). Also see this related [Commonsware blog post from 2016](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/24/system-alert-window-now-more-hidden-than-ever.html)

Comment: And [this medium post for additional historical context](https://medium.com/android-news/what-happened-to-chat-bubbles-heads-in-android-a30597f36115)

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for commenting. I am not sure if they use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW. In the Implementation section, they say "We implemented a prototype of M-Aegis using Java on Android, as an accessibility service. This is done by creating a class that extends the AccessibilityService class and requesting the BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE permission in the manifest. This allows us to interface with the UIA library"

Comment: If the paper authors are using their own accessibility service, then [releasing for the Google Play Store today would have encountered additional restrictions](https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/11/12/google-will-remove-play-store-apps-use-accessibility-services-anything-except-helping-disabled-users/) and [use the required target API for app submissions & updates](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk). So while the privacy concern is valid, Google has been changing both the policy and API itself.